# Move everything up a column if cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some formulas that check some stuff from the applications and writes something on the A:A and B:B column. The problem is that whenever a new application comes in it adds a new row, therefore making my formula go down a row and leaving the new application's A:A and B:B row empty. I want it to move A:A and B:B column up a row whenever a new row appears.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fKUJNXp43bIVbWz1p1xws76trdgDsRUBYOLYMDl2vXw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: for that you will need a script because I see that somewhere like on A470 you have manual input so arrayformula wont do

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheets Scripts: check if cell above is empty and copy the cell below to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258992/google-spreadsheets-scripts-check-if-cell-above-is-empty-and-copy-the-cell-belo)